# How long is the Error 429 TooManyRequests cooldown?

Tags: httprequest, http-status-code-429

I accidentally caused my code to send over 4500 requests to the [News API](https://newsapi.org/) and now I am locked out of the API response.

The News API website just tells to *back off for a while* in their Error documentation, but there is no actual waiting time mentioned. I've already waited over 3 hours.

Is the cooldown specific to the server or are these things universally same?

Do I need to wait to tomorrow (24 hours) ?

There was no Retry-After header as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's company - specific.  Try their KB, forums, support contact info.

Comment: Yeah, I got reply from their support. 500 requests / 12h => 1k/day. So I need to wait about 8 more hours....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got reply from the API support. 500 requests / 12h => 1k/day.